# Asp.net Mvc: Invoke logic on each controller/action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got some logic I want to execute each time a action returns a view. The logic needs to know the name of the action and the controller. At the moment I am working with a filter on each controller/action but sometimes I want all the actions that return a view to use this logic. So adding filters everywhere seems like extra work I can avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the [OnActionExecuting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting.aspx) or [OnActionExecuted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuted.aspx) method to provide common behavior for all actions in a controller.  If you want it to apply to multiple controllers you can create a base controller class with this override and have those controllers that need this behavior derive from the base controller.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext )
{
     ... common code here ...
}

public override void OnActionExecuted( ActionExecutedContext filterContext )
{
    if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
    {
        ... common code here ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to let all the controllers derive from that base class?

Comment: Sure.  They all derive from Controller now.  Just change the base class when you create a new controller.

Comment: But what if you have a project that already has 20 controllers. Do you manually update them all or can I tell all controllers to derive from the new base controller in one location?

Comment: They'd have to all be updated manually, I suppose.  You'd only have to write tests for the functionality on the base controller, though.  Re-basing even 20 classes doesn't seem like a bad trade-off in reducing the filter decoration of all of your actions.  Make sure though that it is really an action you want applied everywhere or you'll end up writing a lot of "switch" code in the base controller method to account for different scenarios.  This would be a sign that you should use the filter method.  I use the base controller method to inject the user's chosen theme onto the page, for example.

Comment: Okay, that's pretty clear. Thanks for taking the time to answer all my questions.

Answer (score 1):

To know action and controller name from within the filter:

```
String ActionName = filterContext.ActionMethod.Name;
String ControllerName = filterContext.Controller.ToString();
```

To apply filter to *all* actions, define `OnActionExecuting` on a base Controller class and then subclass it.

I've asked a specific [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347365/asp-net-mvc-not-executing-actionfilters-on-redirect-and-throw-httpexception) on how to only filter actions that return a view...